# Can't pass a value to Alert function in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, alert

I need to give a alert message to confirm whether one want to delete the selected data.. So far I'm able to produce the alert message. But Is it possible to add a data to alert message.? coz I tried to add the data to alert, but alert is not working when passing data to alert function.

```
<c:forEach items="${instituteList}" var="instituteList">
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>${instituteList.instituteName}</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick=deleteAlert(${instituteList.instituteName},${instituteList.id})><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >Delete</button></a></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>

<script>

    function deleteAlert(String name, String id) {
        var confirmmessage = "Are you sure you want to Delete"+name+"?";    
        var go = "deleteInstitute?id="+id;
        var message = "Action Was Cancelled By User";                                   
        if (confirm(confirmmessage)) {
            window.location = go;
        } else {
            alert(message);
        } 
    }
</script>
```

If I dont pass any values through alert function, alert pops up, but nothing happens if I pass any values.

Comment: "function deleteAlert(String name, String id)" should be "function deleteAlert(name, id)", this is javascript, not java

Comment: Thanks @Hacketo, it works along with the suggestion by Predrag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
onclick="deleteAlert('${instituteList.instituteName}','${instituteList.id}')"
```

You were missing single quotes around parameter value, so when EL is resolved you end up with something like `onclick="deleteAlert(My Institute, 10)"`, which is not good.

Also, what @Hacketo said in the comment, in javascript your function signature should be `function deleteAlert(name, id)`.

Comment: Thanks @PredragMaric, it works after adding single quoted and removing String in script

Comment: btw, it works if the id value is very small like 1,2,3... But it was showing error in inspect element as uncaught error, coz my id is system-uuid which is like this - 402837814a720bb2014a72644e3f0001. I assume this is due to large size of id, is there any way to increate the size of id in script?

Comment: You should put single quotes around `${instituteList.id}` parameter as well.